# Calculate monthly package (product) price in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, oop

I've created e-commerce website, It's about to deliver lunch and dinner service. I am putting question/problem here because i know **here are a lot of legends who can help me.** I have added packages/plan section in website.

```
 1. Weekly
 2. Monthly
```

**Here is the screenshot of page questions form of ordering product:**
[image]
I can easy calculate weekly price like if product price 100 and user selected weekly plan and he choose days from monday to saturday (6 days in a week only), then we can easy calculate price with `6*100 = 600`.
But what about calculating monthly price?
**For example:** If user selected monthly plan and choose 6 days in a week from Monday to Saturday or whatever he wants to choose days names. Then he place his order. Now,

```
6 * 4 = 24 (6 days * 4 weeks)
24 * 100 = 2400 (days * product price)
```

But it's only calculating for 4 weeks, not of full month. I wanna calculate full month. If i check that current month is of 30 days then `4 (weeks) + 2 days` and if current month is of 31 days then `4 (weeks) + 3 days`. Looks like simple and done,  but it's dangerous also, coz what if that + 2 or +3 days are those days which user has unchecked during ordering monthly package.
**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
    $pCartProducts = $pcart->getPlanCartProducts($userid);
?>

<tbody>
    <?php
        if($pCartProducts){
            $finalPrice = 0;
            while($pcPro = $pCartProducts->fetch_assoc()){
                $planName = $pcPro['plan_name'];
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td data-title="Plan">
            <?php echo $planName; ?>
        </td>
        <?php 

            $pro_price = $pcPro['pro_price'];
            $plan_days = $pcPro['plan_days']; // if user selected 6 days in a week
            $totaldays = $plan_days * 4; // 6 * 4 weeks = 24

            // Calculating current month days
            $month = date('m');
            $year = date('Y');
            $cal_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

            if($planName == 'Weekly'){

                $total_price = $pro_price * $plan_days;

            } elseif($planName == 'Monthly'){

                if($cal_days == '30'){
                     $final_tdays = $totaldays + 2; // + 2 days
                } elseif($cal_days == '31'){
                    $final_tdays = $totaldays + 3;  // + 3 days
                } elseif($cal_days == '29'){
                    $final_tdays = $totaldays + 1;  // + 1 day
                } elseif($cal_days == '28'){
                    $final_tdays = $totaldays;      // normal
                }

                $total_price = $final_tdays * $pro_price; // final days * product price

            }

        ?>
        <td data-title="Price">
            <span>Rs./<?php echo $total_price; ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } } ?>
</tbody>
```

**Additional Screenshots:**
[image]
[image]

Can someone please help me to calculate monthly price with selected days in a week?
**Please help me**

Comment: If you go that way the monthly price will be different dependent on which month of the year it is. It might be better to make the monthly price `(52 *$plan_days + 1) / 12`

Comment: But it's not perfect, May be the price will create with this, that price will be extra price or may be low price according to days selected by user

Comment: Unless you want to compute the exact price for every month of every year you will need to make a compromise.

Comment: There are a lot of difficulties doing it this way - which is probably why some services will say that a month is always 4 weeks.

Comment: You have 2 options here, both depend on your definition of a month, **1-** make it a fixed number of days (on my website I say month=30days) or **2-** a month is a month, meaning if today is `2019-02-01` his service will end in `2019-03-01` which means only 28/29 days. I will see if I could give you example in an answer

Comment: @Accountantم yeah i am doing that 2nd option, Actually it's my office work and boss  want that if user order monthly package in `14-09-2019` then it will expire in `14-10-2019`. So basically, my boss didn't fixed days that we'll give service to users for full month. We have created question forms for order so user can select that which days user wants service, so we wanna calculate price according to this

Comment: @Nick My boss don't want compromise. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options

### Option 1

consider the month is fixed number of days like 30 or 28 and continue your work, that simple.

### Option 2

A month is a month, it could be 28 days,29,30 or 31.

OK, in this approach I'm going to calculate the number of days that client will use your service then multiply by the price. I made this approach applicable for both the weekly option and the monthly option based on the days of the week he will use the service, using the power of the built-in `DateTime` Class and it's friends `DateInterval` and `strtotime`. It will loop throw the days from start date and if this day of week e.g(sunday) is selected in the plan, it will count it.

Check it out, and change it as you need, I tried to comment it, however if something not obvious, just comment.

```
<?php
$tz = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
//lets say he chosed the service on Monday and Tuesday and Wednesday
$days = "Monday ,Tuesday, Wednesday";// <-- change to user input
$planDays = translateWeekDaysToNumbers($days);
$planName = "Weekly";// <- change as user input

if($planName == 'Weekly'){
    $weekOrMonth = "week";
} else if ($planName == 'Monthly'){
    $weekOrMonth = "month";
} else {
    //TODO: throw error
}

$startString = "2019-02-01 00:00:00"; // <- change later to "now"
$startDate = new DateTime($startString, $tz);
$afterMonth = new DateTime("@" . strtotime("+1 $weekOrMonth", $startDate->format("U")));

$numberOfDays = $afterMonth->diff($startDate)->days;


$daysOfService = 0; // what we need to calculate

for($i = 0; $i<$numberOfDays + 1; $i++){
    $dateInterval = new DateInterval("P{$i}D");
    $startDate->add($dateInterval);
    if (in_array($startDate->format("w"), $planDays)) $daysOfService ++;
    $startDate->sub($dateInterval);//reset to first day
}

$pro_price = 100;// <--- change to your price from the DB
$totalPrice = $daysOfService * $pro_price;
echo $daysOfService . "\n";
echo $totalPrice . "\n";
exit;

/**
 * expects string like "Monday ,Tuesday, Wednesday"
   separated by comma. case is insensitive
 */
function translateWeekDaysToNumbers(string $days)
{
    
    //dont change the numbers as they are the given by ->format("w")
    $daysNumbers = [
        "sunday" => 0,
        "monday" => 1,
        "tuesday" => 2,
        "wednesday" => 3,
        "thursday" => 4,
        "friday" => 5,
        "saturday" => 6
    ];

    $days = explode(",", $days);
    $planDays = [];
    foreach($days as $day){
        $day = strtolower(trim($day));
        // if unexpected day name is provided
        // an undefined index warning will be shown
        // better than continue silently 
        $planDays[] = $daysNumbers[$day];
    }
    return $planDays;
}
```

Live Demo https://3v4l.org/IVFF7

Comment: It is calculating price for only 1 week?

Comment: Change `$planName = "Weekly";` to `$planName = "Monthly";`

Comment: Ohh i got it , It's from DB, let me implement and check

Comment: Set this variable to "Weekly", or "Monthly" as the user chooses

Comment: I don't know why but it's giving me error of `Warning
: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in
E:\xampp\htdocs\zain\lunch\plan-cart.php
on line
124`

Comment: The `$planDays` needs to be an array of the days of the week that your customer has chosen `sunday = 0, ....... saturday = 6`

Comment: How can i put this in array? Coz it is coming from DB stored value like: `Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc etc`

Comment: just translate them into the day number, I will update the answer. How do you select them from the DB ? each day in separate row? or you `concat` them in 1 cell like `"Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday"` ?

Comment: As u can  see the screenshot of question form above in my question. There is hidden input below days names checkboxes, so i am using jquery to put checked days names in hidden input like: `Monday, Tuesday, Friday, Saturday`

Comment: What are the names of these `checkboxes` ? for example the monday checkbox, what is it's name `$_POST["Monday"]` ? or what ? or are they stored in the DB ?

Comment: Brother, I've added 2 screenshots in my question above. Hidden inputs you will see there in screenshot. Please check them, You'll get it

Comment: @ZainShabir very nice, that is what I wanted to know, I'm updating the answer to tell you how to fill `$planDays` from this string.

Comment: It's giving me error and not showing anything `Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function translateWeekDaysToNumbers() in E:\xampp\htdocs\zain\lunch\plan-cart.php:101 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
E:\xampp\htdocs\zain\lunch\plan-cart.php
on line
101`

Comment: @ZainShabir copy the function `translateWeekDaysToNumbers` in the same file you are using it, the function definition is in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199456/discussion-between-accountant--and-zain-shabir).

Comment: hello there? Brother is it possible that if user order package on `14-09-2019` then will expire on `13-10-2019` instead of `14-10-2019`? How it can be? I have to remove +1 from `for()`?

Comment: @ZainShabir Yes exactly

Comment: Okay brother Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey brother!  @accountant-م, if u r there then can you please come to my this question? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57986692/price-options-for-daily-weekly-monthly-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57986692/price-options-for-daily-weekly-monthly-package)... I am stucked there, my boss wants new things now with this options

Answer (score 1):

You can update your monthly condition by this code

```
         elseif($planName == 'Monthly'){
        // suppose data are saved for on day(means client want order on these day) like Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday 
        // it means 'Friday','Saturday','Sunday' is offday for him

        $weekDay = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'];

        $onDay = 'Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday';

        $onDayArr = explode(',', $onDay);
        $OffDayArr = [];
        foreach ($weekDay as $value) {
            if(!in_array($value, $onDayArr)) {
                $OffDayArr[] = $value;
            }
        }
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($OffDayArr as $$clientOffDay) {
            $str = 'first '.$clientOffDay.' '.$year.'-'.$month.'';
            $monthFisrtOffDay = date("j", strtotime($str));

            while($cal_days >= $monthFisrtOffDay) {
                $monthFisrtOffDay +=7;
                $count++;
            }
        }

        $total_price = $pro_price * ($cal_days-$count);
    }
```

Comment: My first question from your code that how we can check clientOffDay from DB? suppose, if user selected monday to friday and stored in DB like: `Moday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday`, now how we can check offdays?

Comment: I updated the code kindly recheck and please let me know it you faced any issue

Comment: Please check last 2 screenshots in my question above. I've added to show how i am storing days and days names

Comment: Okay assign value on $onday variable  dynamically because you are saved same format as I given

Comment: day_names column value is for $onDay variable

Comment: Replace  this $onDay=$pcPro['days_names']; still face any issue please let me know

Comment: It's only multiplying product price with selected 6 days . It's like it's only for week