# Price options for daily, weekly, monthly package

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating e-commerce website for food delivery for the company where i am working for.
It's not simple e-commerce website and i am creating it custom with `PHP OOP`. It's like packages, full of customizeable, not fixed.
**Here is the graph:**
[image]
**Food Plan 1** is package name which we are creating in admin panel, weekly, daily, monthly is customizeable option, and the prices you can see every option has different price. So this is the concept.
Now, when user click on `choose package` button then questions form will appear, **Here is the form:**
[image]
[image]
I want that my prices (which i have stored in database) will appear only when user click on `daily` and below click on lunch/breakfast/dinner then the prices of `lunch/breakfast/dinner` only for `daily` option. and same with clicking on `weekly` and `monthly`.
**Here is the database screenshot:**
[image]
Here, `d` is for `daily`, `w` is for `weekly` and `m` is for `monthly`.
**Here is my code:**

```
<?php

    $getPlanById = $plan->getPlanById($proId);
    if($getPlanById){
        $result = $getPlanById->fetch_assoc();
            $m_breakfast_price = $result['m_breakfast_price'];
            $m_lunch_price = $result['m_lunch_price'];
            $m_dinner_price = $result['m_dinner_price'];
            $w_breakfast_price = $result['w_breakfast_price'];
            $w_lunch_price = $result['w_lunch_price'];
            $w_dinner_price = $result['w_dinner_price'];
            $d_breakfast_pric = $result['d_breakfast_price'];
            $d_lunch_price = $result['d_lunch_price'];
            $d_dinner_price = $result['d_dinner_price'];

?>

    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h2 class="h2-responsive font-weight-bold mt-5 mb-0">You've choosed <span class="text-primary border-bottom border-primary"><?php echo $result['pro_name']; ?></span> package.</h2>
        <label>Rs./<?php echo $result['m_breakfast_price']; ?></label>
    </div>

<?php } ?>

<div class="select_package_validity">
    <h5 class="h5-responsive font-weight-bold">1. Select your package validity.</h5>
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" id="daily" name="plan_name_selector" value="Daily">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" id="weekly" name="plan_name_selector" value="Weekly">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" id="monthly" name="plan_name_selector" value="Monthly">
    <input type="hidden" name="plan_name" class="form-control ml-4 mt-2 w-50 selected_plan_name" />
</div>
<div class="select_days mt-4">
    <h5 class="h5-responsive font-weight-bold q2_text">2. How many days you need service in a week?</h5>
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_days" id="5" name="plan_days_selector" value="5">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_days" id="6" name="plan_days_selector" value="6">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_days" id="7" name="plan_days_selector" value="7">
    <input type="hidden" name="plan_days" class="form-control ml-4 mt-2 w-50 selected_plan_days" />
</div>
<div class="days_names mt-4">
    <h5 class="h5-responsive font-weight-bold q3_text mb-2">3. Select the days.</h5>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="monday" name="day_name_selector" value="Monday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="tuesday" name="day_name_selector" value="Tuesday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="wednesday" name="day_name_selector" value="Wednesday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="thursday" name="day_name_selector" value="Thursday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="friday" name="day_name_selector" value="Friday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="saturday" name="day_name_selector" value="Saturday">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="sunday" name="day_name_selector" value="Sunday">
</div>
<input type="hidden" class="form-control selected_days_names" name="days_names" />
</div>
<div class="food_time">
    <h5 class="h5-responsive font-weight-bold">4. Select your food time</h5>
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="breakfast" name="food_time_selector" value="Breakfast">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="lunch" name="food_time_selector" value="Lunch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="dinner" name="food_time_selector" value="Dinner">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control selected_food_time" name="food_time" />
</div>
<div class="plan_date_time">
    <h5 class="h5-responsive font-weight-bold">5. When you want to start your package?</h5>
    <input type="text" class="form-control startsfromdatetime" name="starts_from" placeholder="Select date..." />
</div>
```

So, Can you please tell me how can I display prices according to selected `daily/weekly/monthly` with `lunch/dinner/breakfast`?
Should it be done with jQuery or PHP?
**Please help me with this**.

Comment: You got great answer

Comment: Yes @Accountantم but what about dynamic prices, these are static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a combination of PHP and Javascript here. PHP is needed for the backend to get the data from your database in form of an object which then Javascript uses to show the prices on your page if an option is selected.

Note that you'll need to make an ajax call to get your object from PHP to Javascript which can be done using [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for modern browsers.

Here's an example of how it's done:

```js
var validityButtons = document.getElementsByName('validity');
var foodTimeButtons = document.getElementsByName('foodtime');
var prices = {
  breakfast: {
    daily: 120,
    weekly: 110,
    monthly: 100
  },
  lunch: {
    daily: 150,
    weekly: 130,
    monthly: 120
  },
  dinner: {
    daily: 150,
    weekly: 130,
    monthly: 120
  },
};

function calculatePrice() {
  var price = 0;
  var currentOption;
  var showPrice = document.getElementById('price');
  
  /* Iterate through radio buttons to get the checked one */
  validityButtons.forEach(function(button) {
    if (button.checked === true) {
     currentOption = button.value;
    }
  });
  
  /* Iterate through checkboxes to calculate price depending on selected options */
  foodTimeButtons.forEach(function(button) {
   if (button.checked) {
     switch(button.value) {
        case 'breakfast':
          price += prices.breakfast[currentOption];
          break;
        case 'lunch':
          price += prices.lunch[currentOption];
          break;
        case 'dinner':
          price += prices.dinner[currentOption];
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  });
  
  /* Show price */
  showPrice.innerText = price;
}

/* Fire a function when radio button gets clicked */
validityButtons.forEach(function(button) {
 button.addEventListener('change', calculatePrice);
});

/* Fire a function when checkboxes are clicked */
foodTimeButtons.forEach(function(button) {
 button.addEventListener('change', calculatePrice);
});

/* Calculate the price based on selected options on page load */
calculatePrice();
```

```html
Select your package validity:
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="validity" value="daily" checked> Daily
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="validity" value="weekly"> Weekly
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="validity" value="monthly"> Monthly
</label>
<br><br>
Select your food time:
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foodtime" value="breakfast" checked> Breakfast
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foodtime" value="lunch"> Lunch
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foodtime" value="dinner"> Dinner
</label>
<br><br>
Your price: <strong id="price"></strong>
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks, but what about dynamic prices?

Comment: @ZainShabir What do you mean by dynamic prices ? you fire an Ajax to get the prices from the DB, **OR** you set them on page with PHP e.g `breakfast: {
    daily: <?=$d_breakfast_price?>,
    weekly: <?=$w_breakfast_price?>,
    monthly: <?=$m_breakfast_price?>
  },`

Comment: @ZainShabir `<?=$var?>` is a shorthand fro `<?php echo $var?>`

Comment: Yes brother @Accountantم , can you see my update code starts from `Update:` in question? If it can get prices like in that way so please tell me?

Comment: @ZainShabir You already solved it in the update, if you store the prices in hidden inputs, then do like you did in the updated question `Daily: $("input[name='m_breakfast_price']").val()` . **Suggestion**: if you only need these hidden inputs to calculate the price, then get rid of them, and do like my first comment `breakfast: { daily: <?=$d_breakfast_price?>, weekly: <?=$w_breakfast_price?>, monthly: <?=$m_breakfast_price?> },`

Comment: @ZainShabir You could do it like in your example if you don't want to request your data with ajax or you can do it like Accountant م.

Comment: The code i update above in  my question, it's not calculating price properly then, result is like: 0100120150 like this, but, let me do it with ajax as u both suggest me

Comment: @FurkanPoyraz Thanks a lot you too brother

Comment: @FurkanPoyraz Issue has come. I have four packages. `1. All in one Package (daily, weekly, monthly prices availble)` `2. Food plan daily (only daily prices available)`, `3. Food plan weekly (weekly prices available)`, `4. Food plan monthly (monthly prices available)`. So if package has all prices (daily,weekly,monthly) then it's working. But if only daily/monthly/weekly prices available then it's not working. It's not calculating prices. See database screenshot i have posted before in my question.

Comment: @Accountantم Can you see this issue brother?

Comment: Ohh solved. It was because of empty, but may be method can be wrong so brothers, check the method, I just check if price is in database then send price otherwise send 0 instead of empty. **Like this:** `Daily: <?= $d_breakfast_pric ? $d_breakfast_pric : 0; ?>,`  Is it okay?

Comment: @ZainShabir I'm not sure about the precedence here, better put them inside a brackets `Daily: <?= ($d_breakfast_pric ? $d_breakfast_pric : 0;) ?>`